# How to automatically cancel file open prompts using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have dynamic text strings created for external links to closed workbooks in excel that need to be converted to formulas. Some of the files do not yet exist, but I need the links created as formulas. When I execute the following code, I get prompted to open the non-existent file. Is there a way to automatically cancel the prompts so that the formula is entered regardless? It's annoying cancelling a gazillion prompts manually!

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim path As String, r As Single, c As Single
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For c = 0 To 29
        For r = 0 To 1000
            path = Worksheets("String formulas").Range("a3").Offset(r, c)
            Worksheets("Transformed data").Range("bl3").Offset(r, c).Formula = "=" & path
        Next r
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this updated code

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim path As String, r As Single, c As Single
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For c = 0 To 29
        For r = 0 To 1000
            path = Worksheets("String formulas").Range("a3").Offset(r, c)
            If fso.FileExists(path) = True Then
                Worksheets("Transformed data").Range("bl3").Offset(r, c).Formula = "=" & path
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by toggling `Application.DisplayAlerts`.

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim path As String, r As Single, c As Single
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For c = 0 To 29
        For r = 0 To 1000
            path = Worksheets("String formulas").Range("a3").Offset(r, c)
            Worksheets("Transformed data").Range("bl3").Offset(r, c).Formula = "=" & path
        Next r
    Next c

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```